# Pandas groupby counting values > 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas `df` of the following format

```
MATERIAL    DATE         HIGH    LOW
AAA       2022-01-01     10      0
AAA       2022-01-02     0       0
AAA       2022-01-03     5       2
BBB       2022-01-01     0       0
BBB       2022-01-02     10      5
BBB       2022-01-03     8       4
```

I am looking to transform it such that I land up with the below result

```
MATERIAL      HIGH_COUNT    LOW_COUNT 
AAA            2              1         
BBB            2              2
```

Essentially for `"HIGH_COUNT"` and `"LOW_COUNT"` I want to count the number of occurrences that column was greater than 0, grouped by `"MATERIAL"`.
I have tried to do `df.groupby(['MATERIAL']).agg<xxx>` but I am unsure of the `agg` function to use here.

Edit:

I used

```
df.groupby(['MATERIAL']).agg({'HIGH':'count', 'LOW':'count})
```

but this counts even the `0` rows.

Comment: what did you use as input to `.agg`?

Comment: @PaulH just edited and added the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a boolean DataFrame and `groupby` + `sum`:

```
out = df[['HIGH', 'LOW']].gt(0).groupby(df['MATERIAL']).sum().add_suffix('_COUNT').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  MATERIAL  HIGH_COUNT  LOW_COUNT
0      AAA           2          1
1      BBB           2          2
```